# Error in Pig script execution from Java

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig

I am using the following code to run pig from java:

```
import org.apache.pig.ExecType;
import org.apache.pig.PigServer;
public class Pigtest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            PigServer pigServer = new PigServer(ExecType.MAPREDUCE);
            runQuery(pigServer);
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void runQuery(PigServer pigServer) {
        try {

            pigServer.registerQuery("input1 = LOAD '/pigtest.txt' as (f1:int, f2:chararray);");
            System.out.println("File found!");

            pigServer.registerQuery("store input1 into '/pigtest_out';");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

How to resolve this?
But it giving the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "chmod": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:286)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:354)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:337)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.execCommand(RawLocalFileSystem.java:481)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:473)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.setPermission(FilterFileSystem.java:280)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.mkdirs(FileSystem.java:261)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.configureCommandLineOptions(JobClient.java:573)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:761)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:730)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.jobcontrol.Job.submit(Job.java:378)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.jobcontrol.JobControl.startReadyJobs(JobControl.java:247)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.jobcontrol.JobControl.run(JobControl.java:279)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:189)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:133)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1021)
    ... 16 more

16/03/11 15:05:00 ERROR mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher: Failed to produce result in: "file:/pigtest_out"
16/03/11 15:05:00 INFO mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher: Failed!
```

Answer (score 0):

It says:

`Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified`

Looks like, your input file **/pigtest.txt** is not present in HDFS.

**Load** and **store** statements expect HDFS path in MAPREDUCE execution mode. Make sure,that these data paths are HDFS filepath.

Answer (score 0):

Pig is unable to write the output into /pigtest_out. Please check if you have all the rights to create the file in "/" location. Try to place the output in your user home folder.